# How to ping IPv6 address of link-local from container attached to bridge network

Tags: docker, containers, iptables, docker-network

I followed the instructions from docker official document(https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/) and establish a container running with bridge network. As for IPv6 routing rules, the link-local addresses (with prefix fe80::/10) can only be used to communicate with those nodes connecting to the same `link` or `bridge`.

However, I could ping the link-local IPv6 address of container from host while the reverse direction does not work. I cannot ping link-local IPv6 address of host from container.

There are three possible solutions:

1. Tunneling between these two bridges
2. Add ip6tables rules that forward request to fe80::/10 addresses
3. use docker `host` network and modify iptables rule to filter request to those internal port

I'm sure that option 3 would work but I prefer option 2 for the slight modification of existing network/docker infrastructure.

I appreicate any comment or reply.